# CSS not applying correctly in Zend Framework

Tags: css, zend-framework

I am new to the Zend framework.

If I access my Zend application by going to http://localhost/zendapplicationfolder/contact it displays correctly with css applying correctly but if I access the Zend application by going to http://localhost/zendapplicationfolder/contact/ (added a forward slash), the page displays but css is not applied, but if I view the source, the css link is embedded normally between the head tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dcode to include the CSS should be in a layout file, and **should** use the baseurl helper instead of manually writing the link to the css file.

Helper class:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl
{
    function baseUrl()  {
        return Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

Code in the layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?=$this->baseUrl();?>/your/path/from base url/your.css" />
```

Comment: the code i used:
<? $this->headlink()->appendStylesheet('css/screen.css', 'screen,projection'); ?>
<? $this->headlink()->appendStylesheet('css/ie.css', 'screen,projection', 'IE'); ?>
<? $this->headlink()->appendStylesheet('css/print.css', 'print'); ?>
<?= $this->headlink(); ?>

Comment: Just add the baseUrl I gave you to the url you have:
... $this->baseUrl().'/css/screen.css'......

Comment: Tried it and i got

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'BaseUrl' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;./views\helpers/;./application/views\helpers/' in

Comment: Of course, You must create the class (see code above) as a view Helper, in the helper directory and name it according to what ZF expects.

Comment: copied the Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl and saved the file as Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl.php in helpers folder under views folder, but i still got the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'BaseUrl' was not found in the registry;

Comment: This is as far as I can help on this platform, now you need a forum where you can past your configuration and check what you are doing wrong. Can you create any view Helper at all?

Comment: OK - Save the file as BaseUrl.php and not the name you gave it.

Comment: thanks for ur help. am new to Zend Framework and i guess i can't.i will very much appreciate if you can show me how to create a Helper probably i would get the rest from there. thanks.

Comment: thanks for ur time. u really tried. but haven't gotten it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your project layout I suspect that you could solve the problem by using `/css/screen.css` rather than `css/screen.css` That forward slash would give you an absolute path to your css directory rather than the relative one you are using.

For example, this works: `<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css') ?>`
 while this does what you describe: `<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/main.css') ?> the only diff is the forward slash in front of css.`

Comment: thanks for the response. i will give you more info on my directory layout:

webroot/
  library/
  application/
     controllers/
     models/
     views/
       scripts/ 
       filters/
       helpers/
     layouts/
  css/
  index.php
  .htaccess

thats the directory structure.

Comment: sorry, my last comment didnt show the way i wanted it, but i can explain. my application, library, and css folder is in my webroot root folder. I tried what you suggested but its still not working.

Comment: index.php is not in your webroot? It needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had to change something to my codes when the stylesheets were added. Turns out that all I needed to change was to add the forward slash as pointed out by gaoshan88 (thank you!):

href="stylesheets/main3.css"

to

href="/stylesheets/main3.css"